# the configuration for jgroup

Tags: sockets, networking, jgroups

I started two jgroup process in single machine using `JChannel channel=new JChannel();`
It will use default XML configuration file in jgroups-all.jar called **udp.xml**.

Then I viewed port usage by executing netstat command.
The result is following.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxx\Desktop>netstat -ano | find "45588"
  UDP    0.0.0.0:45588          *:*                                    9304
  UDP    0.0.0.0:45588          *:*                                    2492
```

The number 9304 and 2492 is the JVM process id and 45588 is port id.

What I want to know is why the two processes can use the same port 45588 in one host, and what does the IP **0.0.0.0** stand for?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This might give your last question's answer:

When IP 0.0.0.0 is shown means they are not connected to a TCP/IP network. Having this address, a computer cannot be reached or communicate with any other devices over IP.